# c# rearranging class object based on property values?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

The problem is :
We have model id as input parameter to a function and we need to shift that model id at the top among car that have luxury=false. The luxury car should remain at the same position.

```
class Car
{
  int ModelId;
  bool IsLuxury;
}
```

Sample car objects:

```
 1. new Car(1, true)
 2. new Car(19, true)
 3. new Car(1, true)
 4. new Car(7, true)
 5. new Car(8, false)
 6. new Car(9, false)
 7. new Car(1, false)
 8. new Car(25, false)
 9. new Car(9, false)
 10. new Car(1, false)
```

For example if input modelId=1, the list order should change like:

```
 1. new Car(1, true)
 2. new Car(19, true)
 3. new Car(1, true)
 4. new Car(7, true)
 5. new Car(1, false)
 6. new Car(1, false)
 7. new Car(8, false)
 8. new Car(9, false)
 9. new Car(25, false)
 10. new Car(9, false)
```

The cars with luxury=true remains at same rank [Rank 1 to 4],

the cars with modelId=1(input) and IsLuxury=false takes the next positions,

and other cars come in order subsequently (model not 1 and IsLuxury=false).

I want to code this in C#. I have a solution which returns me correct answer but i am not sure of its performance.

```
var res = lst.Where(c => c.IsLuxury== true)
.Concat(lst.Where(c => c.ModelId == 1 && c.IsLuxury== false))
.Concat(lst.Where(c => c.ModelId != 1 && c.IsLuxury== false)).ToList();
```

Can someone suggest some other way in c#, or using linq to achieve this in a better way?

Comment: You could create a custom class that implements [IComparer<Car>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx) and then just call `lst.OrderBy(c => c, new CustomComparer())`.

Comment: I don't understand really the criterion for the order. You don't seem to sort the cars really according to the model id. Is this just a special case with the Id == 1 ? because the places 9 and 10 are not sorted...

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: @MongZhu: Yes since id=1 is assumed input parameter, the cars with modelId=1 will be pushed up to topmost position in cars which have (luxury=false). We can't change order of cars with (luxury=true) and they will be at the top in input as well as output list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, using `IComparer<Car>`:

```
class CarComparer : IComparer<Car>
{
    private int _sortModel;

    public CarComparer(int sortModel)
    {
        _sortModel = sortModel;
    }

    public int Compare(Car car1, Car car2)
    {
        if (car1.IsLuxury)
            return car2.IsLuxury ? 0 : -1;
        else if (car2.IsLuxury)
            return 1;

        if (car1.ModelId == _sortModel)
            return car2.ModelId == _sortModel ? 0 : -1;
        return car2.ModelId == _sortModel ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

And then you'd use it like this:

```
int modelToSortBy = 1;
var res = lst.OrderBy(c => c, new CarComparer(modelToSortBy));
```

Comment: the modelId==1, here 1 is variable that can change for each call i.e. it can be 2 next time

Comment: Perfect. The output looks ok. But can you please tell would  this be better in performance than using .Where...Concat...Concat. Since sort would be O(nLogn) and where/concat operations all are O(n). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Not sure, you'd have to benchmark it. I'd expect it to be highly dependent on the number of cars in the list. At any rate, I'd use it because it's reusable and results in much simpler code in the caller.